# Conversion into a time format

Tags: sql-server, time

there's a query where I get this error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Here's the query:

```
Select cast(RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE as date) as RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE, dtvl18, cast(RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE as time) as RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE_2, tdvl18
from #a1
left join #b1
on ADNR18=PATIENT_ID
and INST18=isuf_lab
and STNR18=request_number
and cast(RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE as date)= cast(cast(dtvl18 as varchar) as date)
and cast(RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE as time)=cast(cast(tdvl18 as varchar) as time)
```

The problem definitely lies in the last clause, since when I remove it, everything works )but I need that one). Namely, the problem is in conversion of tdvl18 (decimal(4,0), null) into a time format.
As it can be inferred, the tdvl18 field looks like this, for example: 947, 1525, 2359 etc. How can these decimal values be converted into a time format (hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn)?

Thanks!

Comment: please add some sample data and desired output as it's difficult to understand how `947, 1525, 2359` should be formatted as time values.

Comment: Well, 947, 1525, 2359 are sample data. Desired format - 09:47:00.0000000, 15:25:00.0000000 etc. Is that possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because SQL Server is failing to recognise string values as valid times. So your current errors can be reproduced with:

```
declare @someval as varchar(10) = '525'    
select cast(@someval as time)

-- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

If you format the values with a `:` in the correct place (before the last 2 digits) using the **[STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188043.aspx)** method, then the conversion should work for your values:

```
declare @someval as varchar(10) = '525'
select cast(stuff(@someval, len(@someval) - 1,0, ':') as time)

-- 05:25:00.0000000
```

This seems to work directly on decimal values too so you can avoid casting to `varchar` first:

```
declare @someval as decimal(4,0) = 525   
select cast(stuff(@someval, len(@someval) - 1,0, ':') as time)

-- 05:25:00.0000000
```

Changing your last clause to this might work, assuming `RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE` is casting to a time value correctly:

```
and cast(RESULT_APPROVE_FULL_DATE as time) 
   = cast(stuff(tdvl18, len(tdvl18) - 1,0, ':') as time)
```

Comment: @Yan no problem, you can mark this as the answer using the tick mark next to the up/down vote button if this solved your problem.